# If my VBO class references vertex arrays, is data still stored on the GPU?

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vao

Quite simply, my question is this.  My code is below for a C++ header file that keeps track of and handles a vertex buffer object in OpenGL.  In order to comply with core standards, it must use vertex arrays (VAO).  Since `glGenVertexArrays()` and other related methods are called, is this rendering method still have information stored on the GPU or in RAM?

```
class VertexBuffer
{
private:
    int vertCount;

    GLuint vertArray;
    GLuint vertBuffer;

public:
    VertexBuffer();
    void renderInterleaved();
    void createInterleaved(GLfloat*, int);
    void destroy();

    GLuint* getVboId();
};

VertexBuffer::VertexBuffer()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertArray);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertBuffer);
}

void VertexBuffer::renderInterleaved()
{
    glBindVertexArray(vertArray);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    int stride = 7 * sizeof(GLfloat);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*) 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertCount);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void VertexBuffer::createInterleaved(GLfloat* data, int vertices)
{
    vertCount = vertices;
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices * 21 * sizeof(GLfloat), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void VertexBuffer::destroy()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertBuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertArray);
}

GLuint* VertexBuffer::getVboId()
{
    return &vertBuffer;
}
```

Comment: `a vertex buffer object or is it a simple and less efficient vertex array  object` What?

Comment: @Drop I made changes to the question.

Comment: VAOs just contain metadata describing the structure of a buffer. They're poorly named - should really be called a Vertex Descriptor Object or VertexArrayMetaStruct or something.

Comment: @DavidLively: Nonsense. They also store the buffer object itself, which is attached to the VAO by the `glVertexAttribPointer` command.

Comment: Any OpenGL calls you make, wherever they are and however they are made, will always have data stored on the GPU's VRAM, rather than the computer's main RAM. As for your class, it makes no sense because a VBO is not an object, and it is not clear as to what you're intending to draw with your VertexBuffer class. The most you can do is abstract most of the OpenGL functionality with C++ function calls, but that is tiresome and impractical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "vertex buffer object" is, and has always been, a misnomer, created by the unfortunate naming of the extension that introduced buffer objects.

There is no "vertex buffer object." There is only a [buffer object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object), which represents a linear array of OpenGL-managed memory. Buffer objects can be used to store vertex data for rendering operations, but there is nothing *intrinsic* about any particular buffer object that lets it do that. It is only a question of how you use it.

If your object encapsulates the parameters you would use for `glVertexAttribPointer`, then it is not encapsulating just a buffer object. A buffer object does not know how to render itself or what data it contains; it's just a buffer. The closest OpenGL concept it represents is a vertex array object.

But your code isn't really using VAOs either. Every time you call `renderInterleaved`, you're setting state that's already stored as part of the VAO. All of those `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray` calls are recorded into the VAO. That's something you ought to set up once, then just bind the VAO later and render with it. So yes, it is a less-efficient VAO.

But your class encapsulates *more* than a VAO. It knows how to render itself. So the best name for your class would be "mesh" or something of that effect.

Comment: I renamed my class and file to MeshRenderer.